# Where are my MongoDB user-managed databases? They're not in admin, local, or config

Tags: mongodb, authentication, user-controls, roles

I created some users and also some databases for them to manage. The problem is that at admin's database system.users i can see the users but the databases are nowhere to be found. With the command: show dbs in mongo shell i get the admin, config and local host. The databases that the users manage are not in any of them. Anyone knows what's going on?

I tried to find the databases but they are not in admin, local host or config but as you see on the picture, i have user Developer to a db named Customers and another user to a db named sales and those dbs are nowhere.

Comment: The photo: 
https://ibb.co/q9YrdK1

Comment: Have you inserted any data into a collection in one of those databases yet?

Comment: No, not yet. I created the user that manages those databases via: db.createUser({user: "developer", pwd: "1234", roles: [{role: "readWrite", db: "Customers"}]}) in admin database.

Comment: Well after too much trial and error i figured out what is going on. I was in admin database and i created 2 users with the following commands db.createUser({user: "developer", pwd: "1234", roles: [{role: "readWrite", db: "Customers"}]}) and db.createUser({user: "developer", pwd: "1234", roles: [{role: "readWrite", db: "Sales"}]}). I could see the users with the db.system.users.find() but i could not see the databases. Therefore, i created the databases (Customers db and Sales) and only then i could delete the users and from inside the daatabases that they manage.

Comment: Long story short looks like that you can create the users in admin database that will manage other databases but they will become active only when those databases will be created. Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Please don't add "solved" to your question title or body. If you've found your answer yourself, great! Do add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Comments are difficult to read and prone to deletion, with answers having the full benefit of formatting, as well as the possibility to get you more upvotes.